# pages controller but route to root/title

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, routes

I've been using static pages in my rails app (ie "/about"  "/contact" etc); the client wants to be able to create pages, control/change the content and still keep the default root/page route.

I've got a page controller with title /content and am using FriendlyID elsewhere, but I'm not sure how I can best change the default /page/about to map to /about

What would be the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question what you need is:

```
get :about, to: 'pages#about', as: :about
```

Running rake routes, you will get:

```
about GET    /about(.:format) pages#about
```

In your links or controller use `about_path`.

Comment: Yes, understood; but what I mean is if these are DYNAMIC - ie someone creates an 'about' page, how can I dynamically create that 'about' route? Or a 'boozefest' page -- assuming for the time being that the route will be the slug of the page (title with '-' for spaces) and all handled by FriendlyID, how can I change  /page/about or /page/boozefest to respond to /about  or /boozefest etc.

Comment: It's a bit older (only a year) but I think this railscast might be the way I'm going to go (near the end):  http://railscasts.com/episodes/117-semi-static-pages-revised?view=asciicast